# output as [object SequelizeInstance:transaction] than json object

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have created a var called trans which created table data will stored but when I am trying to console that var it printing as [object SequelizeInstance:transaction]…  please help me

```
let  err, trans, user, card , wallet;
let transaction_info = req.body;   

trans = await to(transaction.create(transaction_info));
console.log('order <<<<<<' + trans);
```

output of that console log

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `transaction` (`id`,`name`,`cardnum`,`amount`,`amountsplit`,`netamtdebt`,`addedon`,`payumoneyid`,`txnid`,`txnstatus`,`txnmsg`,`email`,`mobile`,`bankrefnum`,`custcardnum`,`pgtype`,`productinfo`,`status`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'dinesh','1004000000000077','125','865','120','2008-12-02 04:35:51','8532651','615659','success','successfully posted','dineshgrt@gmail.com','98798615','516516161','65461531','individual','updated succesfully!!!!','success');

order <<<<<<,[object SequelizeInstance:transaction]
```

when I tried to console with json.stringfy

```
console.log('order <<<<<<' +  JSON.stringify(trans));
```

the output is

```
order <<<<<<[null,{"id":415,"name":"dinesh","cardnum":"1004000000000077","amount":"125","amountsplit":"865","netamtdebt":"120","addedon":"2008-12-02T04:35:51.000Z","payumoneyid":"8532651","txnid":"615659","txnstatus":"success","txnmsg":"successfully posted","email":"dineshgrt@gmail.com","mobile":"98798615","bankrefnum":"516516161","custcardnum":"65461531","pgtype":"individual","productinfo":"updated succesfully!!!!","status":"success"}]
```

i am not getting why its printing like array of null, object requires only object

Comment: Have you tried using the `then` function as in the [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/transactions/) ? A transaction is not a result.

Comment: hii @Seblor, previously its worked fine without then function

Comment: What module are you using, and can you add `transaction_info` in your question ?

Comment: using http module, transaction_info is like this {
 "name"  :    "dinesh",
 "cardnum" :   "1004000000000077" , 
 "amount"  :  "125",
 "amountsplit": "865",
 "netamtdebt" :  "120",
 "addedon"     : "2008-12-02 10:05:51",
 "payumoneyid" :"8532651",
 "txnid"       :"615659",
 "txnstatus"   :"success",
 "txnmsg":"successfully posted",
 "email"  :"dineshgrt@gmail.com",     
 "mobile"  : "98798615",  
 "bankrefnum" : "516516161",
 "custcardnum" : "65461531",
 "pgtype"      :"individual",
 "productinfo" : "updated succesfully!!!!",
 "status"    :"success"
}

Comment: You are using the `http` module for creating mysql transactions ?

Comment: no for creating MySQL tables I am using orm sequelize js

Comment: @seblor I solved it by removing the 'to' in await function like this trans = await transaction.create(transaction_info);

Comment: using `await` is the same as using the `then` function, because `transaction.create` returns a transaction that acts as a promise.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `console.log('string' + obj)`, it will cast the object to a string: `[object Object]`.

What i would recommend is use a comma which bypasses the cast.
`console.log("string", obj);`

or in your case
`console.log('order <<<<<<', trans)`

Comment: using comma aslo it is printing like same

Comment: order <<<<<<[null,{"id":415,"name":"dinesh","cardnum":"1004000000000077","amount":"125","amountsplit":"865","netamtdebt":"120","addedon":"2008-12-02T04:35:51.000Z","payumoneyid":"8532651","txnid":"615659","txnstatus":"success","txnmsg":"successfully posted","email":"dineshgrt@gmail.com","mobile":"98798615","bankrefnum":"516516161","custcardnum":"65461531","pgtype":"individual","productinfo":"updated succesfully!!!!","status":"success"}]

Comment: i don't know what library you are using, but i'm guessing that's actually the structure of the returned object.

Comment: maybe its returning an array so it can be accessed like `[err, obj]` ?

Comment: I am using sequelizejs

Comment: I got it just removed to in await          trans = await transaction.create(transaction_info)